# RAKE DB not able to migrate

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

```
C:\Users\MEGHA\bbbb>rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: C:/Users/MEGHA/bbbb/db/migrate/20140402130040_create_comments.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
C:65535:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Migration is

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.integer :post_id
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: THIS IS NEW ONE.pls help

Comment: @SAGAR: It is difficult sometimes to judge when a similar problem is a new question, or just a refinement to existing question. You should at least give feedback on the previous question, and select a correct answer before creating new question that is so similar. Something like "thank you, that helped but now I get a different error" . . . and if that does lead to a new question, then please remember to *accept* the answer from the old question that helped you.

Comment: @SAGAR run this and show the trace `rake db:migrate --trace` please.

Comment: m newbie..sory........next time wil comment correctly

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+S%C3%A4G%C3%A2rB%C3%BDali/posts

Comment: pls c the post post clicking the abv link

Answer (score 1):

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

may  be its help you ...